# Text auto refreshing in google chrome (rendering issue)

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, cross-browser, text-rendering

Look carefully below two images, the Q letter(g and y also has this issue), some period of time (5 or 6 seconds) in Google chrome render the text something like to `image 01` even though original text is `image 02` other web browsers are render the correct form of text which is `image 02`, but chrome some period of time suddenly shows the `image 01` and change back to `image 02`, I just put this text in `<span>` tag, I would like to know how to fix this.

image 01
[image]

image02 [image]

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code it is hard to diagnose the problem, but it looks as if the characters might be getting chopped off at a horizontal line - Q, g and y are all characters that extend further down than most. The last time I had this type of issue I had a fixed height for my div in CSS, and the content was too big to fit inside it. Changing the height of my div so that it was bigger than the content meant that Chrome wasn't rearranging my document to make everything display properly.